# fs.writeFile не работает на Heroku Node.js

Tags: node.js, heroku

У меня есть Discord бот на node.js, понадобилось чтобы он сохранял файл.

```js
    fs.writeFile('test.txt', 'test', (err) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
    })
```

Когда я на своём компьютере запускаю бота, то все работает отлично, но если я запускаю это на Heroku, то ничего не работает. Как я могу это починить?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39813677/writing-file-in-heroku-filesystem-and-reading-it-with-web-app

Comment: Подозреваю, что нет прав на запись и это написано в err. В любом случае «вы не должны этого делать» и по ссылке выше есть объяснение почему